# How to make a Python print loop

Tags: python

I need a little bit of help. I just started programming. I wanted to try to make a sort of computer terminal that would ask for a user and password *(For example jcd;bionicman)* and when you would write in some sort of loggin that is in the registry, it would show certain text (For example *"Welcome Back JC. Denton)* But, when I write in the user, it just ends the process. How do I make it so that, when I write in the loggin and press enter, it would show the text, and then ask for another user: Here is an *example*

```
Program: Enter Loggin
User: jcd;bionicman
Program: Welcome back JC
Program: Enter new Loggin
```

I know its probably a really simple solution, but everyone has to start somewhere, right?

Here is my progress so far:

```
    password = input()

if password == "jcd;bionicman":
    print("Terminal Accessed. Welcome Back JC")


else:
    print("Unknown Terminal Loggin, Try again.")

while 3 > 2:
    print("Insert Terminal User and Password")
    break
input()
```

This sort of works, but it only asks for another user once, meaning you can enter a loggin twice before the process ends.

edit: Adding a while: true, sort of broke something, now when you write a wrong loggin, it wil not say ("Unknown Terminal Loggin, try again") instead it will just ask for a new user, same with a correct loggin.

Comment: Please share the code you have tried so far.

Comment: Please edit your question and attach your codes

Comment: Where is your reserch

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response

Comment: I added research

Comment: `but everyone has to start somewhere, right?` yes but SO should be your last resort. Read books, read the documentation, search the internet, look up tutorials on YouTube even. SO it not a python tutorial website.

Comment: [How to debug small programs.](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)
|
[What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953)
|
[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/843953)

Comment: Do not vandalize your posts. By posting on this site, you've irrevocably granted the Stack Exchange network the right to distribute that content under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/) for as long as it sees fit to do so. For alternatives to deletion, see: [I've thought better of my question; can I delete it?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)

Answer (score 1):

You should use a While loop.
For example, (* Make sure to add a break)

```py
while True:
  print("foo")
```

What you are trying to accomplish can be done with this code:

```py
joesPassword
while True:
  continueLoop = input("Hey! Want to continue (Y/n)")
  if continueLoop=="n":
    break
  user = input("Welcome! What is your username? ")
  passw = input("Hello, "+user+"! What is your password? ")
  if passw==joesPassword:
    print("Hey, Joe! You got your password correct!")
  else:
    print("Aw man! Your password is wrong!")
```

Comment: Fun fact, if you're using a modern version of Python (3.6+) you can use f-strings to make this string interpolation better looking. Instead of `"Hello, "+user+"! What is your password? "` you can write `f"Hello {user}! what is your password? "`. Alternatively, even old versions of Python support `str.format`. `"Hello, {}! what is your password? ".format(user)`

Answer (score -1):

You'll want to use a `while` loop. Put this before your print code:

```
while True:
```

Then, indent the print code.

Comment: This is an infinite loop... This is bad advice without seeing the actual code... Please try to answer only well-asked questions. Right now the question is too general. You can ask the OP for clarifications in the comments